# Angular File upload validator failed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I tried to build validator for uploaded file in front end using angular. My validator is simple. I put function `onFileChange(event)` on file input form to get properties from file that would be uploaded. Then I tried to filter it. Just png, jpg, jpeg and pdf file can be uploaded. But it did not work as expected. When I upload png file, it shows alert popup. This is my `onFileChange(event` on `component.ts`

```
onFileChange(event:any){
    if(event.target.files.length > 0){
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
      if(this.selectedFile.type != "image/png" || this.selectedFile.type != "image/jpg" || this.selectedFile.type != "image/jpeg" || this.selectedFile.type != "application/pdf" ){
        alert("File type must be png,jpg,jpeg and pdf")
      }
      console.log(this.selectedFile)
    }
  }
```

And this is my `html` file

```
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Pilih File</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
          </div>
```

Hope someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: add a `console.log(this.selectedFile.type)` and select a .png file and see what happens.
you could also use `debugger;` to see the content of `this.selectedFile`

Comment: yes, I did. ```console.log(this.selectedFile.type)``` shows ```image/png``` when i upload ```png``` file. But it still did'nt work as expected. But when i remove other file validator, and just put one validator (ex: png or pdf file) it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `||` instead of `&&`

```
onFileChange(event:any){
  if(event.target.files.length > 0){
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files?[0];
    if(this.selectedFile){
      // no file selected
      return;
    }
    if(this.selectedFile.type !== "image/png" &&
    this.selectedFile.type !== "image/jpg" &&
    this.selectedFile.type !== "image/jpeg" &&
    this.selectedFile.type !== "application/pdf" ){
      alert("File type must be png, jpg, jpeg or pdf")
    }
  }
}
```

our you could do the opposite:

````
if(this.selectedFile.type === "image/png" ||
    this.selectedFile.type === "image/jpg" ||
    this.selectedFile.type === "image/jpeg" ||
    this.selectedFile.type === "application/pdf" ){
    // the file is OK
} else {
    alert("File type must be png, jpg, jpeg or pdf")
}
    ```
````